# Why is PHP throwing throwing a "Cannot Redeclare" error at a local, included function?

Tags: php, include

Here's my problem: I have one file that contains a local function (VRC_Header.php). Here it is:

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; //set a custom session name
    $secure = false; //set to true if using https
    $httponly = true; //This stops javascript being able to access the session id

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); //Gets currtent cookies params
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); //Sets the session name to the one set above
    session_start(); //Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(); //regernates the session, delete the old one
}
```

It's simple enough. I include this file in every public page. For instance,

```
include_once('VRC_Header.php');
include_once('../Classes/VRC_MasterOO.php');
include_once('../Classes/VRC_Secure_Login.php');

//Start a secure session
sec_session_start();
```

My problem is occurring between my login page to a `php` processing page. The submission occurs via a post `jQuery` function. This second page contains code identical to the above:

```
include_once('VRC_Header.php');
include_once('../Classes/VRC_MasterOO.php');
include_once('../Classes/VRC_Secure_Login.php');

//Start a secure session
sec_session_start();
```

Unfortunately, my jQuery function replies with this:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sec_session_start() (previously declared in E:\Additional Programs\xampp\htdocs\Vista_Ridge_Territory_System\PHP\Scripts\VRC_Header.php:14) in E:\Additional Programs\xampp\htdocs\Vista_Ridge_Territory_System\PHP\Scripts\VRC_Header.php on line 24

Note that my jQuery function presents the reply - meaning that I believe the problem resides in the second file. Hence, the "cannot redeclare." Why is this happening? I've not had this issue before with local functions.

Any input is appreciated.

Note: I have removed the include function in both files. If I do, `PHP` throws another error: "`sec_session_start()`" is not defined."

The intermediate jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.login-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#reply').remove();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $("input").prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.post('VRC_LoginProcess.php', formData, loginMessage);
    request.fail(function() { 
        $('.header').append("<span id=\"reply\">Login Failed. Please try again in a few minutes.</ span>"); });

    function loginMessage(data) {
        $('.header').append("<span id=\"reply\">" + data + "</ span>");
        $("input").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: what is line 14 and what is line 24?

Comment: Are you sure you used `include_once` and not `include`?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Yep...That was my first thought - but it didn't work. I don't get it, why does it believe that I am wanting to redeclare the function?

Comment: @Manatax Line 14 is specifically `$session_name = 'sec_session_id';`. Directly before that is the start of the function. Line 24 is `session_regenerate_id();`. That is right before the end of the function.

Comment: @Mlagma Remove the includes from jquery called function and try. If didn't work try vice-versa.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar What do you mean? I'll edit it my post to include the jQuery function. If I understand you correctly, the jQuery doesn't have any "includes."

Comment: @Mlagma yes remove the includes from jquery called php file.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I just did. I lost my constants that were included in that file (database credentials), and since a session couldn't be started, `$_SESSION` variables were not included.

Comment: is not the jQuery. It's the pointed php. Try commenting out session_regenerate_id();

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Ok, I rewrote some of my code to get around some needless errors. It works, but I don't know why. They are two separate files, why would it not need the include? In any case, it is causing another issue. It's not saving the session variables between the two files.

Comment: @Manatax I did that. I've hear that a few times before. Its my understanding that `session_regenerate_id()` only creates a new session id - unless of course it includes true, which would create an entirely new session.

Comment: well... session has to be recalled when using ajax, but it's the same session while you are on the same domain. If you don't particularly need to regenerate the ID, then I wouldn't suggest that you do it. You just destroy it upon logout.

Comment: Good point. I've read that `regenerate_session_id()` was created to aid in preventing session fixation. Is it really worthwhile?

Comment: @Mlagma in reply to your question above, `why would it not need the include?` - it's because it's being included by something else that you're not seeing. It's dangerous to leave it like this with includes happening that you don't understand. See my answer for some hints on tracking down where that second include is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is this error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sec_session_start() (previously declared in E:\Additional Programs\xampp\htdocs\Vista_Ridge_Territory_System\PHP\Scripts\VRC_Header.php:14) in E:\Additional Programs\xampp\htdocs\Vista_Ridge_Territory_System\PHP\Scripts\VRC_Header.php on line 24

The **only way** for this error to occur is if you have included `VRC_Header.php` twice. This has nothing to do with jQuery, and nothing to do with sessions or regenerating session ids. The two different line numbers are just pointing to the start/end of the function.

Try putting an `echo()` command above the function, and you should see the echo happening twice. Even better, put the following code above your function, and it'll display a more useful error message, including a backtrace that will help you see how the file is being included a second time:

```
if (function_exists('sec_session_start')) {
    debug_print_backtrace();
    die('Trying to define sec_session_start() a second time');
}
```