# Fatal Error: Cannot redeclare contact_us() (previously declared in dmp/inc/function.php:690) in dmp/inc/function.php on line 690

Tags: php

my Main index.php has below code.

```
    <?php
    //fetch top header part
    include 'inc/header.php'; ?>
    <div id="wrap">
        <?php
        //fetch slide part
        include 'inc/slider.php';
        //fetch home category part
        include 'inc/home_cat.php';
        //fetch top course part
        include 'inc/top_course.php';
        //fetch Footer of main page
        include 'inc/footer.php'; ?></div>
</body>
```

And my header file consist of below code

```
<?php include 'function.php';
echo signup();
echo login();
//Session start
session_start();
?>
<div id='header'>
    <div id="up_head">
        <div id="link">
```

And my function.php has below code in 190 line number

```
function contact_us()
{
    if (isset($_POST['contact_us'])) {
```

But Its working fine in my local system but gets fatal error when tried to host in server.

Comment: You are creating same function name twice. Change your function name : contact_us to something else. It will solve your issue.

Comment: @Tuhin even I tried that but error same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from my last comment, follow from here please. Somehow your file is loading twice so the function.
Wrapped up the function by checking --

```
if( !function_exists('contact_us')){
 function contact_us(){
   //functions scripts
 }
}
```

Also, don't create function with same name. Otherwise your script will stumble.

Comment: Only once i have included function file and only one time i have declared contact_us and many function in function.php

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are including your `function.php` file multiple times (maybe you are including two differents files that are each including `function.php`, in which case the `function.php` file will be included two times)

In that situation, the `contact_us` function will be declared in both includes, and it will create this error, as you can't have two functions with the same name.

You should use `include_once` instead of `include` to solve this : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: Hi as you can see my index.php I have included 4 files and only in header.php I have included function.php and rest I didnt included function.php

Comment: Are you including any other file in your function.php file?

Comment: No  have only function declaration in function.php file

Comment: see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17377331 to try to debug where that second function declaration comes from

Comment: FYI this php project completely works fine in my local system but error comes in server side